# $push modifies only first document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a query:

```js
db.locations.find({
    "source_id": {
        "$in": [ "1", "3", "4" ]
    }
})
```

Which returns 3 documents.

I'd like to modify these documents with the following command:

```js
db.locations.update(
    {
        "source_id": {
           "$in": ["1", "3", "4"]}
    }, 
    { "$push": {"services": "IN_EUR"} }
)
```

But I get only first document updated. Why is that? Documentation on [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) doesn't say that `<query>` should return single document.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3):

If your intention is to update multiple documents then add the `multi` parameter:

```js
db.locations.update(
    {
        "source_id": {
           "$in": ["1", "3", "4"]}
    }, 
    { "$push": {"services": "IN_EUR"} },
    { "multi": true }
)
```